# Table not found, problema con Spring Boot y Java EE

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, java-ee

Estoy haciendo una app con DevonFW, usando Eclipse como IDE, y Java EE con SpringBoot. El caso es que tengo el siguiente código para testear el backend, insertando datos de prueba SQL:

```
INSERT INTO Visitor (id, modificationCounter, username, name, password, phoneNumber, acceptedCommercial, acceptedTerms, userType) VALUES (0, 1, 'mike@mail.com', 'test', '1', '123456789', '0', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO Visitor (id, modificationCounter, username, name, password, phoneNumber, acceptedCommercial, acceptedTerms, userType) VALUES (1, 1, 'peter@mail.com', 'test', '1', '123456789', '1', '1', '0');
INSERT INTO Visitor (id, modificationCounter, username, name, password, phoneNumber, acceptedCommercial, acceptedTerms, userType) VALUES (2, 1, 'pablo@mail.com', 'test', '1', '123456789', '0', '1', '0');
INSERT INTO Visitor (id, modificationCounter, username, name, password, phoneNumber, acceptedCommercial, acceptedTerms, userType) VALUES (3, 1, 'test1@mail.com', 'test', '1', '123456789', '0', '1', '0');
INSERT INTO Visitor (id, modificationCounter, username, name, password, phoneNumber, acceptedCommercial, acceptedTerms, userType) VALUES (4, 1, 'test2@mail.com', 'test', '1', '123456789', '1', '1', '0');
INSERT INTO Visitor (id, modificationCounter, username, name, password, phoneNumber, acceptedCommercial, acceptedTerms, userType) VALUES (5, 1, 'test3@mail.com', 'test', '1', '123456789', '0', '1', '0');
INSERT INTO Visitor (id, modificationCounter, username, name, password, phoneNumber, acceptedCommercial, acceptedTerms, userType) VALUES (6, 1, 'test4@mail.com', 'test', '1', '123456789', '0', '1', '0');
INSERT INTO Visitor (id, modificationCounter, username, name, password, phoneNumber, acceptedCommercial, acceptedTerms, userType) VALUES (7, 1, 'test5@mail.com', 'test', '1', '123456789', '1', '1', '0');
INSERT INTO Visitor (id, modificationCounter, username, name, password, phoneNumber, acceptedCommercial, acceptedTerms, userType) VALUES (8, 1, 'test6@mail.com', 'test', '1', '123456789', '0', '1', '0');
INSERT INTO Visitor (id, modificationCounter, username, name, password, phoneNumber, acceptedCommercial, acceptedTerms, userType) VALUES (9, 1, 'test7@mail.com', 'test', '1', '123456789', '0', '1', '0');

INSERT INTO DailyQueue (id, modificationCounter, name, logo, currentNumber, attentionTime, minAttentionTime, active, customers) VALUES (1, 1, 'Day2', 'C:/logos/Day1Logo.png', 'Q001', NULL, '1970-01-01 00:01:00', TRUE, 9);

INSERT INTO AccessCode (id, modificationCounter, ticketNumber, creationTime, startTime, endTime, idVisitor, idQueue) VALUES (1, 1, 'Q001', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NULL, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO AccessCode (id, modificationCounter, ticketNumber, creationTime, startTime, endTime, idVisitor, idQueue) VALUES (2, 1, 'Q002', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '2008-01-01 00:00:01', NULL, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO AccessCode (id, modificationCounter, ticketNumber, creationTime, startTime, endTime, idVisitor, idQueue) VALUES (3, 1, 'Q003', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '2008-01-01 00:00:01', NULL, 3, 1);
INSERT INTO AccessCode (id, modificationCounter, ticketNumber, creationTime, startTime, endTime, idVisitor, idQueue) VALUES (4, 1, 'Q004', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '2008-01-01 00:00:01', NULL, 4, 1);
INSERT INTO AccessCode (id, modificationCounter, ticketNumber, creationTime, startTime, endTime, idVisitor, idQueue) VALUES (5, 1, 'Q005', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '2008-01-01 00:00:01', NULL, 5, 1);
INSERT INTO AccessCode (id, modificationCounter, ticketNumber, creationTime, startTime, endTime, idVisitor, idQueue) VALUES (6, 1, 'Q006', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '2008-01-01 00:00:01', NULL, 6, 1);
INSERT INTO AccessCode (id, modificationCounter, ticketNumber, creationTime, startTime, endTime, idVisitor, idQueue) VALUES (7, 1, 'Q007', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '2008-01-01 00:00:01', NULL, 7, 1);
INSERT INTO AccessCode (id, modificationCounter, ticketNumber, creationTime, startTime, endTime, idVisitor, idQueue) VALUES (8, 1, 'Q008', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '2008-01-01 00:00:01', NULL, 8, 1);
INSERT INTO AccessCode (id, modificationCounter, ticketNumber, creationTime, startTime, endTime, idVisitor, idQueue) VALUES (9, 1, 'Q009', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '2008-01-01 00:00:01', NULL, 9, 1);
```

No hay fallos en el SQL. Pues bien, al desplegar la aplicación con SpringBoot me sale el siguiente error:

```
SQL State: 42S02
Error Code: 42102
Message: Table "DAILYQUEUE" not found, SQL statement:
INSERT INTO DailyQueue (id, modificationCounter, name, logo, currentNumber, attentionTime, minAttentionTime, active, customers) VALUES (1, 1, 'Day2', 'C:/logos/Day1Logo.png', 'Q001', NULL, '1970-01-01 00:01:00', TRUE, 9);
Location: db/migration/1.0/V0008__Master_data.sql
Line: 12
Statement: INSERT INTO DailyQueue (id, modificationCounter, name, logo, currentNumber, attentionTime, minAttentionTime, active, customers) VALUES (1, 1, 'Day2', 'C:/logos/Day1Logo.png', 'Q001', NULL, '1970-01-01 00:01:00', TRUE, 9);
```

No obstante, esa tabla la tengo creada con el siguiente código SQL:

```
create table DailyQueue(
  id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  modificationCounter INTEGER NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  logo VARCHAR(255),
  currentNumber VARCHAR(255),
  attentionTime TIMESTAMP,
  minAttentionTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '60000',
  active BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  customers INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  CONSTRAINT PK_DailyQueue PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Además me salen dos errores más:

```
INFO 648---[               main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener:

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.

INFO 648---[               main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication: Application run failed.

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method filed, nested exception is org.flyway.db.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateException:

Migration V0008_Master_data.sql failed
```

No veo el fallo por ningún lado. Por si alguien quiere más información o quiere replicar la app por su cuenta para investigar mejor el fallo, básicamente estoy siguiendo este tutorial (https://github.com/devonfw/jump-the-queue/wiki/devon4j-overview). Es un framework de uso libre con Java EE en el back y Angular en el front. Muchas gracias, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente el problema era que tenían que estar todos los ficheros sql en la misma carpeta. Simplemente eso.